# Can I get the name of the file currently being read in a for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I want to write a script that takes a word as an argument and searches the current and sub directories' files for the word. if it is found in any of the files it should echo out a message containing the file name and the line the word is found on.

this is what I have so far, but I can't find a way to actually store the file name of the file being read or the line number..

```
word=$1

for var in $(grep -R "$word *")
do   
filename=$(find . -type f -name "*")  ------- //this doesnt work
linenmbr=$(grep -n "$ord" file)     -----------    //this doesnt work
echo found $word in $filename on line number $linenmbr
done
```

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -r SEARCH /path/to/folder`. Otherwise `find . -type f -exec grep -Hn SEARCH {} +`

Comment: PS: Give https://www.shellcheck.net/ a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, any time you are looping, you want to avoid calling utilities (e.g. `grep` and `find`) within the loop. That is horribly inefficient because it will spawn a separate subshell for every utility every iteration. (which for 10 iterations -- that is `20` additional subshells, it adds up quick) So in your case, you call `grep` to feed the loop, and then spawn a separate subshell calling `grep` again within the loop as well as spawning a separate subshell for `find`.

You should think of a way to only call `grep` (or a utility that will provide the needed information) only once, and then parse the output.

If you did want to use `grep`, then calling `grep -rn` within a *process substitution* which is used to feed a `while` loop is probably as good as you are going to get. You can then use the bash builtin *parameter expansions* to isolate the filename and line-numbers which will be about as efficient as bash could get, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate at least 1 input given
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s srch_term\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

while read -r line; do  ## read each line of grep output
    fn="${line%%:*}"    ## isolate filename
    no="${line#*:}"     ## remove filename
    no="${no%%:*}"      ## isolate number
    printf "found %s in %s on line number %d\n" "$1" "$fn" "$no"
done < <(grep -rn "$1") ## grep in process substitution
```

**Choosing A More Efficient Method**

If you can accomplish what you are attempting with one of the stream editing tools, e.g. `awk` or `sed`, you are likely to be able to isolate the wanted information an order of magnitude faster. For example, using `awk` and setting `globstar` you could do something similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar   ## set globstar

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate at least 1 input given
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s srch_term\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

## find all matching files and line numbers
awk -v word="$1" '/'$1'/ {
    print "found",word,"in",FILENAME,"on line number",FNR; next
}' **/* 2>/dev/null
```

Give both a try and let me know if you have further questions.

If you want to compare and ensure both are producing the same output, you can use `diff` to confirm, e.g.

```
$ diff <(grepscript.sh | sort) <(awkscript.sh | sort)
```

(if no difference is reported, the output is the same)