# Setting name of current file being read as variable

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

Using a for loop in a batch file, from a folder full of xml files, I am trying to parse an xml tag but also the file name of the current file being read.

I have searched and this question seems to be the same as mine, but for linux. I am using windows

[Can I get the name of the file currently being read in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544799/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-file-currently-being-read-in-a-for-loop)

From other answers on the forum I have put together this, but unsuccessful.

```
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%b in ('findstr /i /c:"<description>" *.xml') do (
echo %%~na^|%%b>>output.txt
)
)
```

Is it possible to get the xml tag and echo the file name of the file the tag was read from?
kind of like:

```
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%b in ('findstr /i /c:"<description>" *.xml') do (
echo %~n0^|%%b>>output.txt
)
```

Except that will echo the bat file name, not the xml name.

Example final output desired (xml name|xml  tag)

```
Atari 2600|Air Raid
Atari 2600|Airlock
Atari 2600|Alien
Nintendo Game Boy|Addams Family
Nintendo Game Boy|Adventure Island
Sega 32X|Blackthorne
Sega 32X|Mortal Kombat II
```

Appreciate any advice as I am just teaching myself here, I don't mind just being steered in the right direction either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%b in ('findstr /i /c:"<description>" "%%a"') do (
```

should work for you. The current filename is in `%%a`. Your code would attempt to find the string in all .xml files.

Perhaps `findstr /m /i /c:<description>" *.xml` may give you a workable base (as a command - not as a replacement `findstr` command for your batch).

---

Supplementary after comment

```
SET "varlist=applicationpath missing notes junk"

FOR %%a IN (%filename1%) DO (
FOR %%w IN (%varlist%) DO SET "%%w="&for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%b in ('findstr /i /c:"<%%w>" "%%a"') do SET "%%w=%%b"
)
:: Show resulting values from file
FOR %%w IN (%varlist%) DO SET %%w
```

I'm assuming that you are using `%%a` as you will to set up the `.xml` filename - I just used a fixed text file as the source for testing.

Simply establish a list of the variables you wish to extract and alter the string that `findstr` locates in the file. Set the variablename to the value from the located line. If not located, leave set to *nothing* (which is easily tested with an `if defined variablename`  command)

Comment: Thanks so much. I was close but so far haha.
Your solution worked a treat.

Comment: I didn't want to start a new question because I think the answer may be related here.
Please let me know if I should, and apologies if so.
I am trying to read two strings from the same file to two variables in a for loop.
the closest i have gotten is
`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (Windows.xml) do (
    set xml=%%x
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<Notes>" "!xml!"') do (
    set notes=%%i
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%f in ('findstr /i /c:"<ApplicationPath>" "!xml!"') do (
    set game=%%f
echo !notes!>"story\!game!.txt"`

Comment: There should be a `)` after `set notes=%%i` to close the `do` associated with `%%i` and again after `set game=%%f` similarly for the `%%f` loop. And the `%%x` loop also needs closing with a `)` after `\!game!.txt"`. The `(..)` pairs should always be balanced. You're best off using `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces, so `set "xml=%%x"` for instance. But I'll add an amendment to allow you to expand the system.